# WebDriver waiting for page load for continuous AJAX calls in background

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver, pageload, browser-automation

I am testing a web application which needs to refresh one of the header elements every 5 seconds. That header element updates all the users with a message whenever a Quote/Policy is issued through anyone using this same application in a group. So for that, our developers are doing AJAX calls continuously every 5 seconds on all pages and for all users.

For navigating through different pages, I was initially using implicit wait like,

```
DRIVER.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

After that continuous AJAX calls, I had to use WebDriver wait explicit function and look for object visibility when navigating through pages; like,

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(DRIVER, 20);
wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(objID)));
```

(Please note visibilityOfElementLocated is another function which also handles exception handling.)

My issue now is, this explicit calls code changes works great when I run the scripts in IE 8. But, when I run this on IE 9 it still behaves the same and endlessly wait for page to load (or wait for that AJAX call to finish). And, if I stop the browser calls (by pressing Esc or x link), my script continues for that page and hangs again for next page.

Any idea, why IE 9 doesn't work as IE 8 does for page load? Is there a way I can debug this?

PS: I tried updating IEDriverServer but in vain. Also, this works fine on Chrome and FF browser.

Comment: Just more updates: I tried with IE10 and it didn't work either.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but our asp .Net application is using signalR to keep that continuous connections.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why IE 8/9 behave differently.
If you want to wait for AJAX to complete you can call a Javascript statement to check for active calls.
JQuery (which I assume you are using) has `$.active` which gives you the number of currently running ajax calls. So you can use the WebDriver as JavascriptExecutor and call this JS snippet:

```
return typeof $ === 'function' && $.active === 0;
```

When the result is true there is no AJAX in progress and you can continue with your test.

Comment: Thanks Christoph T for the reply. My application must make continuous AJAX calls (to refresh some data), so I will always get that value as true. By the way, do I need to modify that line to make it work? Because I called that line As-Is I was always getting false?

Comment: This is the statement we use in our tests. You can check it here on this page, but I agree it is not useful in your case. So I understand your test needs to wait for the currently running AJAX call to complete, right?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured the reason (sadly not the solution). It's a known issue in IEDriverServer of WebDriver for IE9.

Refer below link:
Issue 6402: IEDriverServer always returns document.readyState != complete for application using SignalR - library

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6402